# How to explicitly specify variables as type dynamic?

Tags: dart

```dart
dynamic x = 2;
```

This doesn't compile. But:

```dart
final int n = 6; /* and */
final y = "Hello world!"
```

both compile.

Is it possible and how to declare variables explicitly as of type `dynamic`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to declare variables explicitly as being type `dynamic`. The code

```dart
dynamic x = 2;
```

compiles and is equivalent to the code

```dart
var x = 2;
```

`var` is shorthand for `dynamic` when declaring variables. Omitting a type annotation is equivalent to making the type annotation `dynamic`.

The difference between `var` and `dynamic` is that `var` is for declaring variables and is not a type; it cannot be the return type of a function (since that is not declaring a variable) and function arguments can omit the keyword `var` (the declaration `f(x){}` is equivalent to the declarations `f(dynamic x){}` and `f(var x){}`).

You only need to explicitly use `dynamic` in type parameters for generic classes where at least one but not all type parameters are `dynamic`, such as `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: This answer is old and outdated; `dynamic x = 2;` still works and is valid, but `var x = 2;` will infer `x` to be of static type `int` (and not `dynamic`), so you have to really be explicit when you want `dynamic` from Dart 2+.

Answer (score 1):

`var x = 2;` defines a variable without explicit type, which is the same as `dynamic`.